# In Eclipse PDT, how to include a Subclipse project into another one?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

In Eclipse PDT, I have several projects which have been checked out with Subclipse. And I want a project to use another one, so I go to "Project Properties > PHP Include Path > Projects > Add" but there are no projects at this place.
When I create a new project directly in Eclipse (ie without Subclipse), I can find it in the place I mentioned above.

So, how can I create dependencies between Subclipse projects ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you are not placing Eclipse project metadata into SVN. If you don't, when you go to pull a project from SVN, it will not be enabled for PHP development or anything else. It will be just a plain container.

Make sure to source control all files starting with '.' in project root such as .classpath and .project along with entire contents of the .settings folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you said, there weren't the .project .buildpath and .settings files on the SVN. So I had to checkout the project using the option "Check out as a project configured using New Project Wizard", Eclipse creates this files for me, and now it works great !